# Virasoro constraints in quantum bosonic string theory

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, string-theory

In the [lecture notes of David Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) he states that for the quantum bosonic string in covariant quantization we have the constraint
\begin{align}
L_n|phys\rangle = 0\tag{2.6}
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
L_n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty<m<\infty}\alpha_{n-m}\alpha_m.\tag{p.30}
\end{align}

If we want to write the sum from $m=1$ to $\infty$ for $n=0$ since $[\alpha_n,\alpha_{-n}]=n$ we get
\begin{align}
L_0=\sum_{m>0}(\alpha_{-m}\alpha_m+m) +\frac{\alpha_0^2}{2}
\end{align}
Tong does not do this calculation explicit and just states that we get an constant term for $L_0$ from the commutation relation and therefore the constraint reads
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{m>0}(\alpha_{-m}\alpha_m) +\frac{\alpha_0^2}{2}-a\right)|phys\rangle
\end{align}
and later that constant $a$ will be chosen to be $1$. I can not see where this constant term comes from, since in my calculation the constraint reads
\begin{align}
\sum_{m>0}(\alpha_{-m}\alpha_m+m) +\frac{\alpha_0^2}{2}|phys\rangle
\end{align}
and certainly $\sum_{m>0}m \neq 1$

Comment: The point is that the term you wrote as $\alpha_{n - m} \alpha_m$ is actually a linear combination of $\alpha_{n - m} \alpha_m$ and $\alpha_m \alpha_{n - m}$ at the quantum level whose coefficients are a priori unknown.

Comment: Do you mean then sign flip in the sum over $-\infty<m<\infty$ when you say linear combination? I dont know which coefficients you are speaking of.

Comment: Did you check eq. (2.7) and the eq. above it? $L_0$ is defined differently.

Comment: I mean that the term you wrote as $\alpha_{n-m} \alpha_m$ is actually $x \alpha_{n-m} \alpha_m + (1-x) \alpha_m \alpha_{n - m}$ at the quantum level where $x$ is unknown.

Comment: Equation (2.7) is the constraint involving $a$ what I wrote in my question. @ConnorBehan can you maybe try to explain why there are this factors $x$ and $(1-x)$ at the quantum level? I can not see that

Comment: @Aralian What Connor is trying to say is that at the classical level the quantities $AB$, $BA$, $\frac{1}{2}AB + \frac{1}{2}BA$, $\frac{1}{4}AB + \frac{3}{4}BA$ and so on are indistinguishable. When you quantise and $A$ and $B$ become (non-commuting) operators, all these quantities are different, so you have to pay the price of commuting $B$ past $A$ to get $AB$ again. This introduces a normal ordering constant.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I did. I used the commutation relation to derive the sum involving the sum over $m$. My point is, that the sum from 1 to infinity over $m$ is not the same as the constant $a$ of david tong, since it is certainly not 1

Comment: At this stage $a$ is unfixed (that's the point of $x$ in Connor's comment). Lorentz and Weyl invariance fix it to be 1 later.

Comment: Yes but where does it come from? Its not clear to me from the previous answers. It would be really helpfull if someone could derive where that $x$ factors come from